# Setting Trajan fonts (Type 1) as default fonts for headers

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I would like to change the default font of all headings in my document to the Type 1 fonts Trajan, whose class is described here:
http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/trajan/

For my document, I am using a template created by previous students. The section related to the headings is reported here:

```
%% Headers for the main body of the text, ie from the contents onwards.
%% These headers are used when the document is single sided.
%% If there is no chapter number then uppercase lettering is used.
%% Format is {left}{center}{right}. \defaultfont sets the font to sans.
\newpagestyle{main}[\defaultfont\bfseries]{%     %\defaultfont\bfseries
  \headrule%
  \sethead%
   {\ifthesection{\thesection{.} \space}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter{.}%
    \space}{}}\ifthesection{\sectiontitle}{\ifthechapter{\chaptertitle}{%
    \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}}}%
   {}{\thepage}%
  \setfoot{}{}{}%
  }

%% If the twoside option is set, the even pages can have different styles.
%% These are defined in the sqaure brackets [left][centre][right]{}{}{}
%% The headers are now controlled by the twomain pagstyle.
\newpagestyle{twomain}[\defaultfont\bfseries]{%
  \headrule%
  \sethead%
    [\thepage]%
    [][\ifthechapter{\chaptertitle}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}]%
    {\ifthesection{\thesection{.} \space}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter{.}%
    \space}{}}\ifthesection{\sectiontitle}{\ifthechapter{\chaptertitle}{%
    \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}}}%
    {}{\thepage}%
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
  }

%% Redefine the plain page style to use the defaultfont for the
%% numbering.
\renewpagestyle{plain}[\defaultfont]{%
  \sethead{}{}{}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
```

Now, I tried to change `\defaultfont` to `\trajan` (as well as removing the `\bfseries` command which would no longer be required), but that created errors in the compilation of Latex. At the moment, I am using PDFlatex.

Could anyone help me out with this problem? Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried the `\trjnfamily` given at the link location?

Comment: Yes, I get a compilation error. I substituted \defaultfont\bfseries and  \defaultfont with that.

Comment: Then please post a *full* MWE.

Comment: Ok, now if I remove the boldface everything is fine. Apparently, you have to use \trjnfamily rather than \trajan as I was using. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested. I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the linked site you are wrong using `\trajan`. Rather you have to use `\trjnfamily`.